# RobotFramework - converting a date that has milliseconds in it

Tags: robotframework

I'm converting the following date

```
${converted_randomization_date}=  Convert Date  2017-01-03 00:00:00.000  date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%s  result_format=%Y-%M-%d  exclude_millis=False
```

But getting the following error:

```
ValueError: 's' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%s'
```

Why is this? Are milliseconds not represented by %s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `%f` for the microseconds - don't worry you're actually providing milliseconds there, [that's the python's formatting string for them](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

```
${converted_randomization_date}=  Convert Date  2017-01-03 00:00:00.000  date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f  result_format=%Y-%M-%d  exclude_millis=False
Log To Console  ${converted_randomization_date}
# logs   2017-00-03
```